# What is there an elusive error in this SQL-request?

Tags: sql, powerbi

I receive this error code with my request in Power BI:

> **Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
> Incorrect syntax near ','.
> ErrorCode=-2146232060
> Number=156
> Class=15**

Why?

Here is my code.

```
select
*
from
klecov.dbo.MariaDB with(nolock)
where
dst = 
IF(
calldate < DATEFROMPARTS(2022,10,01), 
'2110', '2111', '2104', '2508', '2147', '2125', '2158', '2155', '2171', '2173', '2203', '2157', '2141', 
'2110', '2111', '2104', '2508', '2147', '2125', '2158', '2155', '2173', '2203', '2157', '2141'
)
or src = 
IF(
calldate >= DATEFROMPARTS(2022,10,01), 
'2110', '2111', '2104', '2508', '2147', '2125', '2158', '2155', '2171', '2173', '2203', '2157', 
'2110', '2111', '2104', '2508', '2147', '2125', '2158', '2155', '2173', '2203', '2157'
)
or cnum = 
IF(
calldate >= DATEFROMPARTS(2022,10,01), 
'2110', '2111', '2104', '2508', '2147', '2125', '2158', '2155', '2171', '2173', '2203', '2157', 
'2110', '2111', '2104', '2508', '2147', '2125', '2158', '2155', '2173', '2203', '2157'
)
```

Comment: What's your database?  That query doesn't look like valid SQL.

Comment: It's ms sql server

Comment: IN TSQL IF is a statement, not an expression.  And you check for multiple values with IN.